# On click events and dynamically created items in an un-ordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a to do list where users can click on the text of an item in the list and it will strike a line through the text. Users can also add new items to the todo list by entering things into a text input bar. When I first load in the page I hard coded a few items to my list and everything works when I click on the text of these items. When I enter text into the input bar and create a new object for the first time it still continues to work normally. However, when I create a second new object things start acting a little weird. When I click on the text of the newly created object the line goes through it fine, but when I click on the line of the previous ones nothing happens and I can't figure out why.

```js
$('.todo-item').on("mouseenter", function(){
  $(this).css("background", "#E3E1E1");
 });
 $('.todo-item').on("mouseleave", function(){
  $(this).css("background", "white");
 });
 $('.todo-item').on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("strike");
 });
 $('.far').on("click",function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow");
 });
 $(document.body).delegate('input:text', 'keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13&&$("#search-id").val()!="") { // if is enter
        e.preventDefault(); // don't submit form
        let input=$("#search-id").val();
        $( "<div class='todo-item'><hr width='100%'' class='divider' color='grey'><i class='far fa-square'></i>"+input+"<div>" ).appendTo( "#list-todo" );
        $("#search-id").val("");
    }
    $('.todo-item').on("mouseenter", function(){
  $(this).css("background", "#E3E1E1");
 });
 $('.todo-item').on("mouseleave", function(){
  $(this).css("background", "white");
 });
 $('.todo-item').on("click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("strike");
 });
 $('.far').on("click",function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow");
 });

    });
```

```css
strike{
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color:#D6D1D1;
}
.fas{
 padding-left: 140px;
}
#todo-div{
 width:400px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#list-todo{
 background-color: white;
 padding:0;
 padding-left: 2px;
}
.divider{
 margin: 0em;
    border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="todo-div">
     <div id="list-header">To do list<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
     <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="search-id" placeholder="Add to-do item here">
     <ul id="list-todo">
      <div class="todo-item">
       <hr width="100%" class="divider" color="grey">
       <i class="far fa-square">    
       </i>Study for itp-303
      </div> 
      <div class="todo-item" >
       <hr width="100%" class="divider" color="grey">
       <i class="far fa-square">       
       </i>Do laundry
      </div>      
      <div class="todo-item" >
       <hr width="100%" class="divider" color="grey">
       <i class="far fa-square">       
       </i>Make Dinner
      </div>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: A lot of the code that you say works and the code I see you've written isn't working. I'm not seeing any strike through behavior or fading.  Other parts are unnecessary completely (`onmouseover` and `onmouseleave` can be removed and a single CSS class that uses the `:hover` pseudo-class will replace that. Also, since you don't have a `form` element in your code, you don't have to worry about checking for the ENTER key press and cancelling the `submit` event.

Comment: For this assignment I'm supposed to create all event functions through the use of jQuery.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean you need to use events when CSS is all that is necessary. You'r inventing the need for events, when no need exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much simpler than you are making it. Use simple CSS to replace the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to set up your `click` events so that dynamically created elements will have event handlers bound to them.

See comments inline:

```js
// You need to use event delegation to handle the existing and dynamically created elements
$(document).on("click", ".todo-item", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("strike"); 
});

$(document).on("click", ".far", function(){
  // No need to stop propagation on this event
  $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow");
});

$("#search-id").on('keypress', function(e) {
  let input= $(this).val();
  if (e.which === 13 && input !== "") { 
    $("<div class='todo-item'><hr class='divider'><i class='far fa-square'>X </i>" + input + "</div>" ).appendTo("#list-todo");
    $("#search-id").val("");
  }
});
```

```css
/* This simple class replaces your mouseenter and mouseleave event handlers */
.todo-item:hover { background-color:#E3E1E1; }

/* You didn't have the . before the class name */
.strike {
 text-decoration: line-through;
 color:#D6D1D1;
}

.fas { padding-left: 140px; }

#todo-div{
 width:400px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
#list-todo{
 background-color: white;
 padding:0;
 padding-left: 2px;
}


/* You were hard-coding width:100% into each <hr>, but:
  1) width:100% is the default for <hr> anyway
  2) even if it wasn't, you should put the CSS here and not in the tags */
.divider { margin: 0em; border-width: 1px; color:grey; }
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="todo-div">
  <div id="list-header">To do list<i class="fas fa-plus"></i></div>
  <input type="text" name="" class="form-control" id="search-id" placeholder="Add to-do item here">
  <ul id="list-todo">
    <div class="todo-item">
      <hr class="divider" color="grey">
      <i class="far fa-square">X </i>Study for itp-303
    </div> 
    <div class="todo-item" >
      <hr class="divider" color="grey">
      <i class="far fa-square">X </i>Do laundry
    </div>      
    <div class="todo-item" >
      <hr class="divider" color="grey">
      <i class="far fa-square">X </i>Make Dinner
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```